# How can I set custom headers when sending FormData with fetch?

Tags: javascript, forms, fetch, multipartform-data, multipart

I'm trying to post a file using fetch API.

After having problems with getting errors with "Not boundary found" messages I discovered I was doing it wrong:

```
getHeaders() {
  return new Headers({
    'Accept': 'application/json',
    'x-access-token': cookies.load('token'),
  });
}

const data = new FormData();
data.append('file', file);
return fetch(this.concatToUrl(url), {
  method: 'POST',
  headers: this.getHeaders(),
  body: data,
});
```

I was overwritting FormData boundary headers and content-length.

The problem is that a need to set those headers to allow JWT auth. How can I set them without loosing the Content-Lenght and Boundary properties?

Thanks